# ServiceStack Caching

Tags: caching, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am looking to cache an expensive query using ServiceStack.

My idea is as follows

Step 1: Cache entire database view to Redis which expires after a day

Step 2: When client calls API route "/cached/balances/{Date}", the service only returns a subset of the cached database view.

To implement this, I am using

**Request and Response Models**

```
[Route("/balances", "GET", Notes = "A call to Db which extracts the entire Db balance view")]
public class GetBalances : IReturn<GetBalancesResponse>
{

}

[Route("/cached/balances/{Date}", "GET", Notes = "Gets a subsection of cached balanced")]
public class GetCachedBalances : IReturn<GetBalancesResponse>
{
     public int Date { get; set;} 
     public int? EntityId { get; set;} 
}

public class GetBalancesResponse
{
    public List<BalanceView> Result { get; set; }
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
 public object Any(GetBalances request)
 {
    var balances = Db.Select<BalanceView>();
    return new GetBalancesResponse {Result = balances };
 }

 public object Any(GetCachedBalances request)
 {
       GetBalances balancesRequest = request.ConvertTo<GetBalances>();

     // get the cached response
      var allBalances = (CompressedResult)base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
                this.CacheClient, "urn:balances", () => {
                    var service = this.ResolveService<BalanceServices>();
                    return (GetBalancesResponse)service.Any(balanceRequest);
                });

            // filter the results -> this does not work!
            var filterBalances = response.Response.ConvertTo<GetBalancesResponse>().Result.Where(Ar => Ar.Date == request.Date && (Ar.EntityId == request.EntityId || request.EntityId == null)); 

    return new GetBalancesResponse {Result = filteredBalances};
 }
```

The filtering of balances does not work as I cannot seem to convert the compressed result to the ResponseDto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have an answer to my own question.

The ServiceInterface GetCachedBalances can be filtered as per below

```
  public object Any(GetCachedBalances request)
  {
     GetBalances balancesRequest = request.ConvertTo<GetBalances>();

     // cache everything
     var filteredCachedResponse = (CompressedResult)base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
            this.CacheClient, "urn:balances", () => {
                var service = this.ResolveService<BalanceServices>();
                return ((GetBalancesResponse)service.Any(balanceRequest)).Result.Where(Ar => Ar.Date == request.Date && (Ar.EntityId == request.EntityId || request.EntityId == null));
            });

     // filter cached response
     var filteredResponse = base.Cache.Get<GetBalanceResponse>("urn:balances").
                    Result.Where(Ar => Ar.Date == request.Date && (Ar.EntityId == request.EntityId || request.EntityId == null));

      return filteredResponse;
   }
```

Comment: Note the CompressedResult encapsulates compressed serialized bytes in its the final form that they're written directly to the ResponseStream in. So you can't deserialize it back into a DTO, you would need to either store/retrieve the DTO in the cache directly (i.e. not using ToOptimizedResult), or do any processing before you cache the result as you're doing here.

Comment: @mythz - just realised my own answer is not entirely what I am looking for. I was hoping to cache the entire DbView and then only return a subset of the cache. However this does not seem possible as the only way of doing that would be to somehow deserialize it back into a DTO & filter it according to the request parameters.

Comment: You can cache and retrieve DTOs by accessing base.Cache directly.

Comment: I am not sure giving a "Cache" (prefix/sufix) to your DTOs is a good choice. Cache should be inside your service logic, and inside of it, you test if values are cached or not, and update the cache if not present.

Comment: @mythz - thanks base.Cache is exactly what I was looking for. Will update my answer for future references.

Comment: @labilbe - agreed. I was thinking of making the '/balances/' route not visible such no clients can only access the cached route. alternatively it may be best to rename the route from cached/balances to balances